# How do I use Latin Modern fonts outside of Tex?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to install the Latin Modern fonts in my operating system, so they can be used by other applications. However, looking at the [download provided](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download), I get a whole bunch of different OTF files with strange names like `lmromancaps10-oblique.otf`. Now I get that this font file describes what italic small caps glyphs in size 10 look like, but it's just a variation on the base small caps font. When I install all the fonts, though, each variation shows up as a separate, individual font. Am I using these files wrongly?

EDIT: I've installed them on Linux with MATE Font Viewer, and they show up in `fc-list`:

```
$ fc-list | grep lm
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtti10.pfb: LMMono10:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtko10.pfb: LMMonoLt10:style=BoldOblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmbo10.pfb: LMRomanDemi10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmbxo10.pfb: LMRomanSlant10:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtto10.pfb: LMMonoSlant10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtk10.pfb: LMMonoLt10:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtko10.pfb: LMMonoPropLt10:style=BoldOblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtk10.pfb: LMMonoPropLt10:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmb10.pfb: LMRomanDemi10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssdo10.pfb: LMSansDemiCond10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtlo10.pfb: LMMonoPropLt10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmbxi10.pfb: LMRoman10:style=BoldItalic
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssqbx8.pfb: LMSansQuot8:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssbx10.pfb: LMSans10:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmdunh10.pfb: LMRomanDunh10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtt10.pfb: LMMono10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmsso10.pfb: LMSans10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmcsc10.pfb: LMRomanCaps10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtcso10.pfb: LMMonoCaps10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmu10.pfb: LMRomanUnsl10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmss10.pfb: LMSans10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtcsc10.pfb: LMMonoCaps10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssq8.pfb: LMSansQuot8:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssqo8.pfb: LMSansQuot8:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtlco10.pfb: LMMonoLtCond10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtlo10.pfb: LMMonoLt10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmr10.pfb: LMRoman10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssbo10.pfb: LMSans10:style=BoldOblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmcsco10.pfb: LMRomanCaps10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtl10.pfb: LMMonoLt10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmro10.pfb: LMRomanSlant10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssqbo8.pfb: LMSansQuot8:style=BoldOblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtto10.pfb: LMMonoProp10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmtlc10.pfb: LMMonoLtCond10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtl10.pfb: LMMonoPropLt10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmduno10.pfb: LMRomanDunh10:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmvtt10.pfb: LMMonoProp10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmssdc10.pfb: LMSansDemiCond10:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmbx10.pfb: LMRoman10:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/lmri10.pfb: LMRoman10:style=Italic
```

Poking around a bit, LibreOffice gives the correct behaviour:
[image: Desired behaviour displayed in LibreOffice]

GIMP, however, displays each style individually:
[image: GIMP displaying incorrect behaviour]

If I recall, installing the font files using the Windows Explorer context menu Install option also produces the wrong behaviour in Microsoft Windows.

The reason I asked here, as opposed to the Unix & Linux or Superuser Stack Exchanges, is because other fonts are typically distributed and installed as a single file, which gives the desired behaviour---hence my initial suspicion that I was doing something wrong with the files.

Comment: that is expected. Even in plain TeX you would have to load these as separate fonts. It is a specific LaTeX feature that it knows which latin modern font to use at a particular font size and style

Comment: Not only LaTeX feature. Other macro-packages for TeX does the similar job.

Comment: @wipet oh sure optex, context, have same kind of thing, my point was that at the application level these need to be loaded as separate fonts.

Comment: When you say, "each variation shows up as a separate, individual font", can you explain the context a bit more? Show up where? How are installing them? You didn't even mention what operating system you're using, so it's hard to guess, or know whether or not what you're seeing is normal.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for the query; I've updated my post to provide these details.

Comment: Something is wrong if you’re seeing the `.pfb` files. Those are an obsolete format, provided only for backward compatibility with legacy TeX engines, and you want to install only the `.otf` files. Copying them and only them to a subdirectory of `/usr/share/fonts/` and running `fc-cache -f -s -v` should do it on Linux.

Comment: If not, you might have better luck with New Computer Modern (although it provides separate files for 8- and 10-point, instead of the optical sizes of Latin Modern).

Comment: I think gimp always lists the variants separately like that for some reason. If it makes you feel any better, `fc-list | grep -i lm` gives me 73 fonts; yours only has 39. But I agree with Davislor: you should install the opentype (.otf) versions, not the Type 1 (.pfb) versions.